# How to validate properties with accent in a json with JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I need to validate a json response of an api. There´s one property that messes everything up. For simplicity the json I need to validate is:

```
{
  "razón_social" : "Empresa"
}
```

On the other hand the JSON Shema I'm using for validation is:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties":{
    "razón_social": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't match with the JSON Schema. Any idea on how to validate a property with an accent in a JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was when I read the file with the schema. All I needed to change was the line where I read the contents of the file with the schema.

From:

```
File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

To:

```
File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.Default);
```